# Matrix indexing in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find index of lowest value of sub matrix `mA` from matrix `A`. `z` provides the index of lowest value in `mA`. How i can translate this index value of `mA` to the original matrix `A`

```
A = magic(11)
mA = A(3:5,5:7)
[~,rows] = min(mA)
[~,col] = min(min(mA))
z = [rows(col),col]
```

Comment: You basically need to keep track of it, you somehow arbitrarily sliced A to create mA, so you are able to do the inverse (know what mA corresponds to in A)

Comment: If your sub-matrix selection started with `3` on the rows  and `5` on the columns, the first index in `mA` is translated by -2 and the second by -4 (`mA(1, 1) == A(3, 5)`), so to get from `mA` to `A` indices, it should be `z + [2 4]`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A=randi([-10 10],11,11)
n1=3;n2=5;d1=3;d2=3;
mA=A(n1:n1+d1-1,n2:n2+d2-1)
[v1,q1]=min(mA(:))
[m1,m2]=ind2sub(size(mA),q1);
z=[n1+m1-1 n2+m2-1]
```